# How to Hide Class Library From Parent Project

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture, dependencies

We have a Solution with a .NET Core C# API project. The API project relies on a Class Library. The Class Library has dependencies that the API project needs to know nothing about. To make it easier to visualize, here is what I am talking about:

[image]

**Question**: How do I hide some class libraries from the API project, WHILE still making them available to the Class Library called directly from the API project? The goal is to make sure the API project doesn't directly call sub-dependencies of the Class Library it uses.

Failed approaches:

- Use "internal" - doesn't work - the "parent" and dependent class libraries are all different assemblies, i.e. the parent Class Library can't use dependent Class Libraries if they are internal.
- Use "protected" - doesn't work, any class inheritance is shoehorned in here at best
- Use an entirely different solution for the Class Library and its dependencies, import it as NuGet package - too much work for an actively worked-on codebase

Comment: Why isn't it good enough to just not reference those projects from the API project?

Comment: @Crowcoder project dependencies cascade automatically.  So every public API in the nested class library projects will be available to the root project regardless of whether or not it references those projects directly.

Comment: @VSO, I doubt you can get the compiler to enforce this for you through standard C# patterns, but you could [build an analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/getting-started-with-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2022) that would do the job just as well, but would likely have to write it yourself.

Comment: @Crowcoder Because I have junior developers rotating onto my team and I would like the code to be as self-describing as possible. Sure I could leave a comment or train them, or catch it in code review, but it would be nice for it to be "natural and intuitive". Thanks Kirk. I think I looked into this a few years back and never found a solution.

Comment: I guess you could do a little msbuild voodoo to make the sub assemblies non-project references to the top class library.

Comment: I think I want to avoid msbuild / analyzer solutions since it might detract from the readability rather than add to it. Still - really appreciate the answers, thanks guys.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/friend

Answer (score 1):

We can hide the inherited class libraries' access by modifying the default `ProjectReference` section in the `*.csproj` file.

Let's say the solution structure looks like this:

```
API
 |--> ClassLibrary
            |------->SubClassLibrary
```

To hide the `SubClassLibray`'s assemblies in the `API` project, we need to modify the `ClassLibrary.csproj` file as below:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SubClassLibrary.csproj" >
        <ExcludeAssets>compile</ExcludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It works well thank you, it can help with clean architecture implementations @codeninja.sj